# Slack Web API - pulling specific message

Tags: typescript, express, slack-api

According to [these Slack docs](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) (see section called 'Retrieving a single message') - you can use the `conversations.history` method to pull a single message from a channel using a timestamp. I think I've set up my function the correct way, but it always returns the most recent message in the channel, not the specific message I want. This is in spite of me using the correct timestamp

Code is below, can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks

```
/**
 * Pulls a specific message in a channel by timestamp
 *
 * @param {string} workspaceID
 * @param {string} channelID
 * @param {string} ts
 * @returns {string: null} The message
 */
export async function getMessageByTs(workspaceID: string, channelID: string, ts: string) {
  const endpoint = "https://slack.com/api/conversations.history";
  //This function pulls in the correct token for the workspace
  const botToken = await getBotToken(workspaceID);
  const options = {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  };
  const data = {
    token: botToken,
    channel: channelID,
    latest: ts,
    inclusive: true,
    limit: 1,
  };
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(endpoint, querystring.stringify(data),options);
    const resData = response.data;
    if (!resData.ok) {
      console.log("err pulling message ", resData.error);
      console.log("metadata pulling message ", resData.response_metadata);
    }
    if (resData.messages) {
      return resData.messages[0];
    }
    return null;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("the error on message pull is , ", e);
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: I think the bug is somewhere else (e.g. malformed `ts`). Parameters of the query look correct. I just tested it with following call `https://slack.com/api/conversations.history?channel=XXX2YQE67&latest=1600200012.025100&limit=1&inclusive=true`. Perhaps you could log actual url used by axios ?

Comment: You are 100% correct. I didn't think there was any error with the `ts` because I wasn't getting an error on my axios post request. Turns out it was malformed, and so I was always pulling back the most recent message in the channel

Comment: There's an error called `invalid_ts_latest` in `conversations.history` that I assumed would be throw, but wasn't. So as a PSA to others - don't rely on these errors and check your own inputs